# Decoding facebook's blob video url (part II)

Tags: facebook

This a first question for me. Hence I could not add a comment to the original.
I followed the solution and worked as expected.

However, when I tried to download 2 private videos that were part of the same post, only the 1st URL produced the correct video. The inspection of the 2nd URL, showed, as expected, that it is different from the 1st.

[URL 1](https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.25447-6/71578292_953518921678286_1526088906388157710_n.mp4?_nc_cat=103&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfb2VwX2hxNF9mcmFnXzJfdmlkZW8ifQ%3D%3D&_nc_oc=AQkKEBRCAchi696iirK2HwBdjhiLt9RkotACPxm68KKqiN7uUFO7Zx8KcH0LeJ6Ff2c&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=3406ce1c5fba99e9dd03f336b2a39674&oe=5E2AC945)

[URL 2](https://video-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/71644521_424913964804376_8125075193333809152_n.mp4?_nc_cat=111&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImRhc2hfdjRhdWRpb2ZvcnNvdXJjZXBpcGVsaW5lXzEyOF9jcmZfMjNfbWFpbl8zLjBfZnJhZ18yX2F1ZGlvIn0%3D&_nc_oc=AQkwUx8jI8IBp0OvZpCwUgWcXP1YEsOCbeor5tg3_L6MQj9brZ3x-Gii1PKa-u_2W1I&_nc_ht=video-sjc3-1.xx&oh=bcd4ad0c4e5f3fb2fd9e6c15bc4cff59&oe=5D92C76A)

Although I do not think it makes a difference, I observed that the host name starting with "sc-content" or "video".

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you get the URLs from?

Comment: And BTW, the popular way of downloading an FB video using youtube-dl, has the same problem.

Comment: Use the API to get URLs that you can programmetically download.

Comment: WizKid, What is the API that takes an URL of the format I gave in the original question? This is a private video and user/password are likely needed. Thank you!

Comment: There is no API that takes a URL. You use the API to get the URLs. And yes you of course need access tokens to use the API.

Comment: Thank you WizKid! However, youtube-dl does exactly that and fails in the same way.

Comment: Exactly what? Youtube-dl uses the API to get URLs? If they get an error then Youtube-dl should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Specifically, given two URLs (that are not pointing directly to the mp4 files), https://www.facebook.com/abc.def/videos/10210718300672614 and /https://www.facebook.com/abc.def/videos/10210718301752641/, it always downloads the mp4 associated with the first URL. What to do?

Comment: There is no error from youtube-dl. It works as expected in all other cases where posts contain a single video.

Comment: As I said. Use the API to get the video URLs. If you are not using the API it is not supported and Facebook does not allow you to scrape them

Comment: I had a look at the graph api which is, I think, what you are referring to.

Comment: For my purpose, it is a bit too much effort. Nonetheless, why is it the a user does not need to use the API to get a video in high resolution if the post contains just one video? It seems purposefully inconsistent to allow non-API download in one case and not the other. Why is that?

Comment: No idea why there is a difference. Just saying that Facebook does not allow you to scrape.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question described how you bring up the developer window, go to the network tab and observe the various URLs scrolling by as the video is playing. At some point you can copy one of the URLs from said window, strip out bytestart & byteend. This then constitutes the URL I mention.

Answer (score 0):

I did find the answer to my own question after reading some the Graph API documentation on cookies. Thank you WhizKid!

If an FB post contains several videos, the steps below show how to download all videos using youtube-dl 2019.09.28:

- press play on video #1
- ctrl-right click and "Show Video URL"; select all & copy to text editor
- go back to post
- press play on video #2
- ctrl-right click and "Show Video URL"; select all & copy to text editor
- KEY: go back to post and reload page
- within the terminal window, enter: "youtube-dl -u user -p pass URL#1" and/or URL#2

NB. Occasionally you may get "Something went wrong. We are having trouble playing this video". You can reload and carry on; it will eventually play and you can get the video URL as per above.